# Convert Array of Objects to Javascript Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to convert an array of Builds called @builds to a javascript array, doing it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var fail_builds = [];
        var builds = [<%= raw @builds.to_json %>];
        fail_builds.push([6,7],[5,builds.length],[1,2]);
        $.plot("#flot-placeholder", [ fail_builds ]);
    });
</script>
```

But builds.length no matter what, builds.length will return 1, even though roughly 50 builds are stored in @builds.  Here is the schema for the Build model if that might help:

```
t.string   "build_name"
t.string   "status"
t.string   "test_type"
t.string   "target_branch"
t.datetime "time_started"
t.datetime "time_finished"
t.datetime "time_queued"
t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this: `var builds = [<%= raw @builds.to_json.html_safe %>]`

Comment: it didn't work, same as before

Comment: Can you show the generated JavaScript? You might need to remove the square brackets from your code, since they are in the JSON output.

Comment: Have you looked at the output? The problem would be pretty obvious if you had. `[ [ 1, 2 ] ]` is an array of length one as is `[ ]` and `[ { a: 'b' }, { a: 'c' } ]`. JSON knows what arrays are so why are you wrapping the output in an extra set of brackets?

Comment: Thanks haha I forgot i added those

Comment: You need to call json parse from the Javascript. Also json will always be an array or hash so it's probably unnecessary to wrap it in brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say

```
@builds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`@builds.to_json` will evaluate to `"[1,2,3,4,5]"` and thus your JS will end up looking like this:

```
var builds = [[1,2,3,4,5]];
```

An array of an array whose length is 1.

If you are sending JSON strings to the view you should be using `JSON.parse()` instead.

```
var builds = JSON.parse("<%= @builds.to_json %>");
```